# Saving data with coroutines during onPause() (avoiding ViewModel cancellation and global coroutine scope)

Tags: android, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Upon saving some data(to room) during onPause() with

> this.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
>              repo.updateNote(id, text)
>          }

I noticed that save does not happen most of the time, because viewModelScope is cancelled if user is navigating away from the fragment.

Since using some type of global scope seems to be frowned upon for various reasons, is there an elegant way to Fire-And-Forget this db-save without tying it to ViewModelScope?

I could create a service for this but it feels like an ugly hack, I could also use runBlocking which works, but can potentially hang the fragment, I'm looking for an elegant way to do this with coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire and forget is exactly what `GlobalScope` is for: things that shouldn't be cancelled, so just use that.

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){ repo.updateNote(id, text) }
```

Comment: Just note that it is always dangerous to rely on `GlobalScope`. If Android has decided to kill your app, your coroutine will die without even finding out this is about to happen (through cancellation).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - when Android kills your app process due to memory constraints, there's no signal at all, no matter what coroutine scope you are using.

Comment: There are some useful callbacks in `Application` like `onLowMemory` and `onTrimMemory`, which are early signs of an approaching kill. I prefer replacing `GlobalScope` with my `ApplicationScope` for this reason.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - neither of which have any relevance to what coroutine scope you use.

Comment: They do if you tie the lifecycle of the scope to the `onLowMemory` callback. You can start a new job in it after cancelling the existing coroutines.